# Listen to Ethereum transactions

Tags: web3j, java

I need to listen ethereum transactions for current count of addresses using web3j. I know that I can use subscribe to get transactions, but how can I add some filter to listen a certain number of accounts?

```
Subscription subscription = web3j.transactionFlowable().subscribe(tx -> {// some code});
```

Comment: Ivan my man the community is awaiting your return can you please answer me in the discord

Comment: is this subscribe event is like a observer on Kotlin? that will notific me every status change on the Transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to transactions on an account you can do the following:

> web3j.transactionFlowable().filter({tx -> tx.to == "0xaddress" })

However, you should note that under the hood it will be getting every transaction using the rpc endpoint.